# want to add images to textview similar to emoji images (default keyboard) in Xcode 6?

Tags: swift, ios8

I have created custom keyboard from application extension option provided in Xcode 6.I want to access textfield (created in another view controllers) to add my images .similar to Facebook,skype etc text editor.